# Javascript For Loop Using AppendChild

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I'm creating a pixel art maker right now for a lab assignment and I'm currently trying to create a grid from a user form (input height and width of the grid), but whenever I call the function to create the grid on the submission of the form it isn't appending any table rows to my table. I can currently do it easily using jQuery, but I am trying to become better at just using vanilla JS.

EDIT: I am just trying to get rows then do the loop for the tds. One step at a time.

JS

```
function makeGrid(){
  //define grid height/width and pixelcanvas table
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
  var height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
  var width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;

  //remove all children from canvas so if makeGrid gets called again it cleans the canvas
  while (canvas.firstChild) {
    canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
  }

  //Loop for height and add tr to canvas
  for (x = 0; x > height; x++) {
    var row = document.createElement("<tr></tr>");
    canvas.appendChild(row);
  }

}

//Assign the form submit to a variable and put an eventlistener on click that runs makeGrid
// var submit = document.querySelector("#inputSubmit");

document.getElementById('sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  makeGrid();
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: As mentioned by Obsidian Age in his answer, your for loop condition isn't quite right.
In order to help avoid the situation in the future: the second parameter to the for loop condition says "execute this for loop while this condition is true". I'm going to guess that maybe you had written it with the intention that once this condition is met, break the for loop?

Comment: There's more than one problem: `e.preventDefault` should be `e.preventDefault()`. You need to add `tr` elements not `<tr></tr>` elements. Also the loop condition mentions by @obsidianAge. This will get you as far as adding rows to the table.

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks so much for that. I hadn't even noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems. Here I change the child element to `tr` from `<tr></tr>`. Call the function `e.preventDefault()` and fixed the loop condition. I also added the extra loop for columns:

```js
function makeGrid() {
  //define grid height/width and pixelcanvas table
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
  var height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
  var width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;

  //remove all children from canvas so if makeGrid gets called again it cleans the canvas
  while (canvas.firstChild) {
    canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
  }
  //Loop for height and add tr to canvas
  for (x = 0; x < height; x++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    canvas.appendChild(row);

    for (z = 0; z < width; z++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td')
      row.appendChild(cell)
    }
  }

}

//Assign the form submit to a variable and put an eventlistener on click that runs makeGrid
// var submit = document.querySelector("#inputSubmit");

document.getElementById('sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  makeGrid();
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be your `for` loop; you have the `>` back-to-front. Your line
`for (x = 0; x > height; x++)` will never execute, as `x` will never be greater than `0`.

Simply swapping this to `for (x = 0; x < height; x++)` should solve the problem.

Comment: Haha such a simple mistake. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
document.getElementById('sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  makeGrid();
})
```

You're simply *referencing* the function `e.preventDefault`, you're not calling it - in order to prevent form submission, you need to actually call the function:

```
document.getElementById('sizePicker').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  makeGrid();
})
```

I would also highly recommend not implicitly creating global variables as you're doing for `x`. Always declare using `var`, `let`, or `const`. (preferably `const`)